# How to interpret gpsd TPV accuracy info

Tags: gps, accuracy

I want to understand the epx (Longitude error estimate in meters, 95% confidence) and epy (Latitude error estimate in meters, 95% confidence) values in a gpsd TPV packet.

If I have data like this

```
{
 "location": [
      38.38xxxxxxx, -78.90xxxxxxx
  ],
  "epx": 2.522, "epy": 3.285
}
```

, is there a way I can use this info to (i) calculate a more accurate GPS location of the object or (ii) calculate a radius or distance (from the reported location) within which the object is actually located?

P.S. I found some context here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49808276/gpsd-tpv-json-data-has-95-conficence-errors-ex-ept-epx-epy-how-do-you but want to know how to use epx and epy.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it this just gives you a rough understanding of the accuracy of the measurements.

See [here](https://gpsd.gitlab.io/gpsd/gpsd_json.html):

> All error estimates (epc, epd, epe, eph, ept, epv, epx, epy) are
> guessed to be 95% confidence, may also be 50%, one sigma, or two sigma
> confidence. Many GNSS receivers do not specify a confidence level.
> None specify how the value is calculated. Use error estimates with
> caution, and only as relative "goodness" indicators. If the GPS
> reports a value to gpsd, then gpsd will report that value. Otherwise
> gpsd will try to compute the value from the skyview.

So basically you shouldn't and can't improve the accuracy of single measurements with these values. However what you could do is remove measurements which have a relatively worse accuracy.

As an example, if you have a lot of measurements and plot the distribution of the x and y error I would expect that you could get something of a normal distribution where most measurements are close to the mean, some are a lot more accurate and some are a lot worse, for example when they weren't able to connect to a lot of satellites.

Then you can remove all measurements that are outside of the 95th percentile of your accuracy distribution to improve the *overall* accuracy of your data.